# QtQuick or QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qt-quick

When I should use QGraphicsView and When QtQuick is a better choice?
Which is better choice if I want high performance application with highly customized widgets (visual of widgets and its behaviors)?

:?

Comment: Qt Quick has the option of using a QDeclarativeView, which IS a QGraphicsView.  So the two choices aren't mutually exclusive.  Perhaps you mean to ask when you should use QML vs. C++?

Comment: I'm looking for a right base to creating UI. As i understood, QtQuick and QGraphicsView represents a UI base. I know that it is possible to combining this two technology, but which should be base for individual projects? When I should use QtQuick/QML and when I should use QGraphicsViews/C++ as base UI technology? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For high performances, you should use Qt and C++ instead of QML and JavaScript. So let's use a `QGraphicsView` in this case.

However, creating a widget is much more easier and faster with QML than QtWidget. It may be great for making prototypes or for interfaces which are made by designers. QML is a convinient solution if you do not need high performances. You can also have a look at [this article](http://cdumez.blogspot.fr/2010/12/ways-to-improve-qml-performance.html) to improve the QML performances in your program

Comment: Thank you. It looks sufficient for me. Also I afraid from using QtGraphicsView and making it so bad performance. Is there any triks/note on working with QtGraphicsView?

Comment: You can still have a look at the Qt documentation and tutorials on their website for this.